# Is i(G) equivalent to i_l(G), the local independency set of BN?

Tags: graphical-model, bayesian-network

> Reference: Koller, D., & Friedman, N. (2010). Probabilistic graphical models: Principles and techniques (Nachdr.). MIT Press.

Bayesian network $\mathcal{G}$ encodes that for any node $X_i$, there are always local independencies with any node that isn't a descendant of $X_i$, with the condition of all parent nodes:
$$
\mathcal{I}_{\ell}(\mathcal{G}) := \{X_{i} \perp NonDecendants_{X_i} \mid Pa_{X_i} , \forall i\} 
$$

However, Koller & Friedman(2010) defined another $I(G)$, which means all conditional independencies in BN $\mathcal{G}$. So I have 3 questions:

1. whether $\mathcal{I}_{\ell}(\mathcal{G})$ is equivalent to $I(\mathcal{G})$? It seems that a BN only contains local dependencies.
2. the proposition "$P$ factorized over $\mathcal{G}$" is equivalent to (a) "$\mathcal{I}_{\ell}(\mathcal{G})\subseteq \mathcal{I}(P)$", or (b) "$\mathcal{I}(\mathcal{G})\subseteq \mathcal{I}(P)$"?
3. if we know that $\mathcal{I}_{\ell}(\mathcal{G})\subseteq \mathcal{I}(P)$, whether $\mathcal{G}$ is an I-map of $P$?